# Terraform GCP Cloud function using Github

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-functions, terraform, serverless

I want to create a Google Cloud Function using Terraform but want to pull the source code from Github.

I managed to do this zipping up the function and copying it into Cloud Storage using Terraform, but I do not like this workflow as I have to run a script to kick things off. I rather just do a PR on Github and see the new code in GCP.

I already setup Google Cloud Source Repositories to source from my Github.

The Terraform doc to use the "**source_repository**" argument is not clear to me. What I would like to do is just grab the source from **HEAD** on the **master** branch.

This function source code is located under the sub-folder:

“**cloud-functions/training_data**”

There are two files inside the function folder:

- “main.py”
- “requirements.txt”

I just would like to know how to specify the “source_repository” argument in this case.

Comment: Can you share the Terraform code with what you've tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, working for Big Corp.
I just need to understand the format of "source_repository".

Comment: Can you produce a [mre] that doesn't include anything proprietary?

Comment: fine any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across this problem as well.

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/cloudfunctions_function.html) says to format the url value to be, `https://source.developers.google.com/projects/*/repos/*/moveable-aliases/*/paths/*`

To get this to work...hypothetically, say my source code and my repository had the following information...

```
project: kalefive-project
repo: kalefive-functions-repository
branch: master
directory_in_repo_with_src: src/functions/bin
```

Then the resulting url that worked for me was...

```
source_repository = {
  url = https://source.developers.google.com/projects/kalefive-project/repos/kalefive-functions-repository/moveable-aliases/master/paths/src/functions/bin
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that's exactly what I figure out and got it working! The docs could be better written imho.

Comment: This works. Make sure that the service account that terraform uses, has read access to the source repo.

Comment: @lilline  service account has access to read/write on source repo but still not able to deploy the code. The function is being created perhaps . 


Error waiting for Creating CloudFunctions Function: Error code 13, message: Failed to retrieve function source code

Answer (score 0):

```
source_repository = {
  url = https://source.developers.google.com/projects/kalefive-project/repos/kalefive-functions-repository/moveable-aliases/master/paths/src/functions/bin
}
```

incase the above syntax is not working just use it without an equal sign.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "js_function" {
    source_repository  {
      url = https://source.developers.google.com/projects/kalefive-project/repos/kalefive-functions-repository/moveable-aliases/master/paths/src/functions/bin
   }
}
```